# How to pass a string through pipeline steps azureml sdk v2?

Tags: python, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk, azure-ai, azure-ml-component

There is a way to pass a string from a pipeline step to another in azure machine learning sdk v2? E.g.:

```py
def step_1(<inputs>):
    var: str = 'lorem ipsum'
    <function>
    return var  # or
    step_1.var = var

def step_2(var: Input(type='string')):
    <function>
```

The `Output` method from `azure.ai.ml` (or `mldesigner`) doesn't accepts `type='string'`.Thus, I can't define an output like

```py
def step_1(var: Output(type='string'):
    <do something with var>
    <function's end>
```